# how I can use mysql date greater in order by case?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display the users first who's subscription is not ended  yet and then others users who dont have subs_end_datetime.  I have tried with following sql but returns nothing.

```
 $sql = "select * from users order by case when subs_end_datetime <= CURRENT_DATE()  then 0 else 1, id";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM users
 ORDER BY (COALESCE(subs_end_datetime, 0) <= CURDATE()), id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1e6a/4)** demo

---

Based on your comments

```
SELECT *, subs_end_datetime <= CURDATE() aa
  FROM users
 ORDER BY (COALESCE(subs_end_datetime, 0) <= CURDATE()), subs_end_datetime DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66be6/2)** demo

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am looking all users to be on top in order by who subscription is not over. For example John subs_ends ends  tomorrow and Jerry subs_end day after tommorrow. and Jack has no subs_ends so the order should Jerry,John,Jack.

Answer (score 1):

This way we show the users whose subscription is not ended yet. We used `>=` insted of `<=` in our query and users who don't have any ends_subscription_datetime already set (`null`).

```
SELECT *
FROM users
HAVING (coalesce(subs_end_datetime, 0) >= current_date() OR
         ((coalesce(subs_end_datetime,0)) = 0))
ORDER BY subs_end_datetime ASC
```

**EXAMPLE:**  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a255c/18